# Python hinting: is it possible that using typing.cast will cause to lose data

Tags: python, python-typing

I observed a very strange behavior when using typing.cast method on dataclasses.

I created these dataclasses:

```
@dataclass(eq=False)
class NodeData:
    ...

@dataclass(eq=False)
class InventoryNodeData(NodeData):
    uid: str = None

@dataclass(eq=False)
class VmNodeData(InventoryNodeData)
   ...
```

I have a node which is an instance of InventoryNodeData, with a 'uid' member:

```
node.uid
Out[25]: 'vm_1'
type(node)
Out[26]: VmNodeData
node.asset_unique_id
Out[25]: 'vm_1'
```

So far so good.
However, once I invoke cast function on this object, this member disappears.

```
str(cast(node, InventoryNodeData).asset_unique_id)
Out[28]: 'None'
```

How does it make sense???

Comment: You flipped the argument order for `cast`; it always returns its *second* argument, not the first, so you accurately found that `InventoryNodeData`, the class, has `None` for that attribute. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cast` signature is `cast(typ, val)`. Easy fix:

```
str(cast(InventoryNodeData, node).asset_unique_id)
```